# Error opening matlab due to Java error

Tags: java, matlab

I was trying to simply open matlab I had a java exception. I didn't do anything except probably update java automagically. Has anyone had this problem before?

This is on MAC OS, yosemite.

Error message:

[image]

Comment: Did you also happen to upgrade to Yosemite?  This is a well-known bug: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/336387 .  The gist of it is you have to patch up a few files that are part of MATLAB.  That thread will tell you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't well known to me. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Let me know if that works.  If it does, I wouldn't mind it if I wrote an answer and you accepted it.  Let me know!

Comment: BTW, if you don't want to sift through that thread, go here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1098655 - This is the direct link to the patch you need to install.

Comment: @rayryeng sure, I don't mind accepting ur answer for ur help :)

Comment: Thanks :)  Get it working first, then when you're ready and if it finally works, go ahead and accept.  I've written an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: If I did anything special apart from what u said, I am happy to include it in a comment so that u can have a concise single answer :)

Comment: That's really nice of you.  Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng I didn't do anything special, just followed the link with more details that u provided. Thnx!

Comment: Sweet!  Good to know.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular error is due to installing a version of MATLAB that was released before the release of Mac OS Yosemite.  Specifically, if you were running a version of Mac OS that is prior to the release of Yosemite, and then you decide to upgrade to Yosemite, you will generate this error when trying to run MATLAB after the fact.

It is a well-known bug that has unfortunately plagued a lot of Yosemite users.

If you consult this particular MathWorks thread: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/336387 , upgrading to Yosemite while having such a version of MATLAB will generate a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on startup.  Fortunately, MathWorks has released a patch to patch up your MATLAB so you can get it running again.

See this link for more details on patching up your MATLAB program.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1098655

Make sure you download the right patch that corresponds to the MATLAB version you have.

Comment: Go the second link in the above answer and follow the instructions carefully. i.e. the link http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1098655

THNX!

Answer (score -1):

yes i had this problem two or three years ago. if you use windows 7 aero theme, then you will get this error. Set the theme windows default, then try to open again. Otherwise please share your os and matlab version with us.

Comment: The OP is using Mac OS Yosemite, not Windows. -1.

Comment: i found an article may helps you to achieve your problem : 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/159016-is-matlab-compatible-with-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite

it refers to a link for hotfix about your problem : 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/159016-is-matlab-compatible-with-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite