# MATLAB startup crashes with El Capitan OS X

Tags: matlab, osx-elcapitan

I just upgraded my mac system to ***El Capitan*** and with ***Matlab 2014b*** I have the same problem that the users with Matlab 2014a and earlier had with Yosemite:

[Error opening matlab due to Java error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28842429/2984179)

I tried to solve this issue by following this

https://youtu.be/GoQnzIyOkB0

but problem is that El Capitan does not let changes to Core Services folder easily and I do not want to change any permissions. Is there any other way that I can solve this problem?
For what it is worth, I transferred MATLAB 2014b from my Mavericks by Time Machine.

Here is the screenshot of error

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the [instructions from The MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1098655)? I try those before following a YouTube video.

Comment: These bug fixes are for up to 2014a versions. I downloaded the patch but does not recognize the my Matlab version.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message or a screenshot of it from your system? Also, you may be more likely to get help for this sort of thing on the  MathWorks forums.

Comment: I just added the error snapshot

Comment: Have you installed [Legacy Java](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US)?

Comment: Yes I did install that.